# Using the MacLaurin series of $\ln(1-x)$ to find a series representation of $\ln2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, real-numbers

**Background**

In a previous problem, I have shown that the Taylor polynomial around $x=0$ for $f(x) = \ln(1-x)$ is $$T_nf(x) = -\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{x^k}{k}$$

**Problem**

Use this Taylor expansion to show that $\displaystyle \ln2 = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n2^n}$.

**My thoughts**

I figured, hey, $\ln(2) = \ln(1-(-1))$ so with $x=(-1)$ I can just plug it into that Taylor expansion. But apparently that Taylor polynomial is only valid for $x\in(-1, 1)$, so I can't do that.

So that's where I'm stuck.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: How about using $\ln 2= -\ln (1/2)$ and  $x=1/2$?

Comment: The Taylor polynomial is actually valid at $x\in[-1,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

The Taylor polynomial is actually valid at $x=-1$, which is right on the boundary.  Using it, we have

$$\ln(2)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n$$

But this isn't supposed to be the answer!  Using log rules, however, one may note that

$$\ln(2)=-\ln(1/2)=-\ln(1-1/2)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n2^n}$$

---

If you hadn't noticed this, however, you could apply an [Euler transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_summation) to get

$$\ln(2)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}$$

Prove that $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}=\frac1{(n+1)}$ so that we have

$$\ln(2)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(n+1)2^{n+1}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n2^n}$$

Comment: Hm, interesting thought.  Can we prove that $\ln(x)=-\ln(1/x)$ using the Maclaurin expansion?  Particularly by using the Euler transform?